# Maven/Eclipse does not copy my tests resources to the target/test-classes directory

Tags: eclipse, maven

When I try to debug my unit tests with Eclipse, my resources are not found (getResourceAsStream returns null) because maven/Eclipse? does not copy them to the target/test-classes. Why are the test classes build but resources not copied?

I did post the answer to this question with the question.

I am using Eclipse 2022-09 with m2e 2.0.1... Maven 3.8.5, maven-resources-plugin 3.2.0.

the pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>MyArticactId</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>MyName</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>MyGropupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>ParentArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: If you could show your pom file and how you compile/run your tests and which Maven version, etc. you are using it might be possible to help...otherwise simply not...

Comment: @khmarbaise I did add the info but I also pointed out the solution in the answer section

Answer (score 2):

Learned the hard way that Eclipse compiled the test classes to the target/test-classes directory but did not copy the resources if maven.test.skip is set to true.

```
<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
```

I have to set maven.test.skip to false to be able to debug tests that require resources. It would have been easier to identify the configuration problem had Eclipse not generated the test class files (the same way Maven does not).

ref: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407636

Comment: The question is why have you defined a property to skip the tests?

Comment: We updated a dependency which caused some tests to fail. We turned off tests while I was investigating.

Comment: You can executed tests from the IDE (or at least from other IDE's) and fix one test after another... Why hard configuring your build to skip tests... even for CI... every build will fail until all tests fixed..?

Comment: Appears the same happens when surefire has skipTests set to true in its configuration.